# Mulesoft version 4 - how to receive and send ISO8583 messages via TCP/IP protocol?

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

I have to receive and send back the response of ISO8583 messages in Mule 4 via TCP/IP protocol.

Please suggest examples or connectors be used.

Comment: What have you researched on the topic?

Comment: You should say Mule 4. MuleSoft is the company name. MuleSoft 4 has no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an ISO 8583 connector available for Mule 4. You could create your own connector using a Java library that implements ISO 8583 and the Mule SDK.